# Issue using Groups: How to set backcolor for specific column when the value is null

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a  column called `totalhours` in my report where I want to set back color to `yellow` when value of column called `outtime` is `null`. So for that i have created a conditional style with following details :

```xml
<style name="TotalHoursBackColor" lineSpacing="Single">
   <conditionalStyle>
      <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{Out_time}.equals( null ))]]>  </conditionExpression>
      <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFF33" lineSpacing="Single"/>
   </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

The above code gives the following output

```
SlNo.    empid       intime         outime    totalhours 
1         100         9:00           13:00       4:00

2         101         9:10           null       yellow

3         105         9:30           13:30
                      14:30          null     

4         103         9:30           18:30       9:00

5         107         9:40           13:40       8:00
                      14:40          18:40    

6         108         10:00          null        yellow

7         106         10:00          13:00
                      14:00          null
```

But, I want the output as follows :

```
SlNo.    empid       intime         outime    totalhours 
1         100         9:00           13:00       4:00

2         101         9:10           null       yellow

3         105         9:30           13:30      yellow
                      14:30          null      

4         103         9:30           18:30       9:00

5         107         9:40           13:40       8:00
                      14:40          18:40    

6         108         10:00          null        yellow

7         106         10:00          13:00       yellow
                      14:00          null
```

Please find the jrxml file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports  
http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="HRIS Employee Time  
Sheet" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555"  
leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
<style name="TotalHoursBackColor" lineSpacing="Single">
<conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{Out_time}.equals( null ))]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFF33" lineSpacing="Single"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <parameter name="Date" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select hr.EmployeeID,convert(char(5), tr.In_Time, 108) as In_time,
       convert(char(5), tr.Out_Time, 108) as Out_time,
convert(varchar(5), sum(datediff(minute, trr.In_Time, isnull(trr.Out_Time, dateadd(hh, 18, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, trr.In_Time), 0))))) / 60)
+ ':' +
convert(varchar(5),sum(datediff(minute, trr.In_Time, isnull(trr.Out_Time, dateadd(hh, 18, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, trr.In_Time), 0))))) % 60)
as TotalHours,
       hr.FirstName, hr.LastName, hr.EmployeeNo
from HR_EMPLOYEES hr
     Left Join HR_EMPLOYEE_TIMESHEET tr
on (hr.EmployeeID=tr.EmployeeID)
     Left Join HR_EMPLOYEE_TIMESHEET trr
on (hr.EmployeeID=trr.EmployeeID)
     where (trr.In_Time BETWEEN $P{Date} AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, $P{Date})
     and  tr.In_Time BETWEEN $P{Date} AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, $P{Date}))
     and hr.locationID=1
group by hr.EmployeeID, tr.In_Time, tr.Out_Time, hr.FirstName,                     hr.LastName,
         hr.EmployeeNo, hr.JoiningDate
order by hr.JoiningDate ASC]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="EmployeeID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="In_time" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Out_time" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TotalHours" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="FirstName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="LastName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="EmployeeNo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="counter" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="EmployeeSerialNumber">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[($V{EmployeeSerialNumber_COUNT} == 1) ? $V{counter} + 1 : $V{counter}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="outtime_check" class="java.lang.Boolean" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="EmployeeOutTime">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[($F{Out_time}.equals(null)&& $V{EmployeeSerialNumber_COUNT}==1)?$V{outtime_check}:$F{TotalHours}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="EmployeeSerialNumber">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{EmployeeNo}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="EmployeeOutTime">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{Out_time}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="466" y="19" width="89" height="32"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["D:\\timesheet\\logo.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="38" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="125" y="0" width="204" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Employee Time Sheet - Bangalore]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="dd MMMMM yyyy">
                <reportElement x="455" y="-2" width="100" height="18"/>
                <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.sql.Timestamp"><![CDATA[$P{Date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="31" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="155" y="7" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="293" y="7" width="86" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[In Time]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="385" y="7" width="76" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Out Time]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="474" y="7" width="59" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Total Hours ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="54" y="1" width="1" height="29"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="466" y="2" width="1" height="29"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="14" y="1" width="527" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="289" y="1" width="1" height="29"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="380" y="2" width="1" height="28"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="57" y="7" width="67" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Employee No.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="128" y="2" width="1" height="28"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="430" y="30" width="111" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="7" width="30" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sl No.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="14" y="2" width="1" height="29"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="54" y="0" width="1" height="22"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="466" y="0" width="1" height="22"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="13" y="-1" width="416" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="14" y="21" width="415" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="541" y="-29" width="1" height="50"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="289" y="0" width="1" height="21"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="380" y="-1" width="1" height="22"/>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="68" y="1" width="44" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{EmployeeNo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="134" y="1" width="148" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" lineSpacing="Single"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{FirstName} + " " + $F{LastName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="128" y="0" width="1" height="22"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="430" y="21" width="111" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="293" y="1" width="76" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" lineSpacing="Single"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{In_time}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="384" y="1" width="76" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" lineSpacing="Single"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{Out_time}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="TotalHoursBackColor" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="477" y="1" width="62" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" lineSpacing="Single"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{TotalHours}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="14" y="1" width="1" height="20"/>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="24" y="2" width="25" height="19">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{EmployeeSerialNumber_COUNT}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement lineSpacing="Single"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$V{counter}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="435" y="34" width="80" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" lineSpacing="Single"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="515" y="34" width="40" height="20"/>
                <textElement lineSpacing="Single"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="41" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Could anybody please help me how to get it

Answer (score 1):

You should change the ***evaluationTime*** attribute of the *textField* with styled text (with *$F{TotalHours}* expression) to the **Band** value.

The working sample.

The input data, *csv* data source:

```
EmployeeID,In_time,Out_time,TotalHours,FirstName,LastName,EmployeeNo
101,9:00,13:00,4:00,Filippo,Inzaghi,1
102,10:00,,,Zineddin,Zidan,2
102,10:00,,,Zineddin,Zidan,2
103,10:00,15:00,5:00,Andriy,Shevchenko,3
103,10:00,16:00,6:00,Andriy,Shevchenko,3
103,10:00,,,Andriy,Shevchenko,3
104,8:00,15:00,7:00,Gennaro,Gattuso,4
104,8:00,10:00,2:00,Gennaro,Gattuso,4
```

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="HRIS Employee Time   Sheet" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <style name="TotalHoursBackColor" lineSpacing="Single">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{Out_time}.length()==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFF33" lineSpacing="Single"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="EmployeeID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="In_time" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Out_time" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TotalHours" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="FirstName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="LastName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="EmployeeNo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="counter" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="EmployeeSerialNumber">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[($V{EmployeeSerialNumber_COUNT} == 1) ? $V{counter} + 1 : $V{counter}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="outtime_check" class="java.lang.Boolean" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="EmployeeOutTime">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[($F{Out_time}.equals(null)&& $V{EmployeeSerialNumber_COUNT}==1)?$V{outtime_check}:$F{TotalHours}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="EmployeeSerialNumber">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{EmployeeNo}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="EmployeeOutTime">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{Out_time}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="31" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="135" y="0" width="183" height="31"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="318" y="0" width="86" height="31"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[In Time]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="404" y="0" width="76" height="31"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Out Time]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="480" y="0" width="59" height="31"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Total Hours ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="50" y="0" width="85" height="31"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Employee Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="31"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sl No.]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="480" y="0" width="59" height="22">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(1==1)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement lineSpacing="Single" markup="none"/>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="50" y="0" width="85" height="22">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(1==1)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement lineSpacing="Single" markup="none"/>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="318" y="0" width="86" height="22"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" lineSpacing="Single"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{In_time}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="404" y="0" width="76" height="22"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" lineSpacing="Single"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{Out_time}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Band">
                <reportElement style="TotalHoursBackColor" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="480" y="0" width="59" height="22"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" lineSpacing="Single"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{TotalHours}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="22">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(1==1)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement lineSpacing="Single" markup="none"/>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="50" y="0" width="85" height="22"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{EmployeeID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="135" y="0" width="183" height="22"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" lineSpacing="Single"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{FirstName} + " " + $F{LastName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="22">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{EmployeeSerialNumber_COUNT}==1]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement lineSpacing="Single"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$V{counter}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="135" y="0" width="183" height="22">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(1==1)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement lineSpacing="Single" markup="none"/>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="435" y="34" width="80" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" lineSpacing="Single"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="515" y="34" width="40" height="20"/>
                <textElement lineSpacing="Single"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be (via Preview function in *iReport*):

[image: Preview in iReport]

If we did not change the ***evaluationTime*** attribute for *textField* (default value is *Now*) the result will be:

[image: Preview in iReport]

*Note*: I've used the *iReport 3.7.6*.

Comment: thanks for your reply, as you suggested i changed but not working 1. for $Out_Time it is set Blank when Null,so i used this new Boolean($F{Out_time}.equals(null)) instead of new Boolean($F{Out_time}.length()==0) 2. when i use band as evaluation time, it repeats each row value in total hours, which i dont want as i mentioned in my question snapshot(for eg:please refer Slno 5 in my ques,if employee enter two times in and out time, the totalhours will only show to the 1st row ) 3. BackColor is coming for single row entry, its only not working for more than 1 row entry(pls refer Slno 7 in my ques)

Comment: What version of *iReport* are you using?

Comment: report made in iReport 3.5.2 but now doing with iReport 5.0.4 where i set to take as 3.5.2

Comment: i checked your sample but same printing repeat values for each row as i mentioned in my first comment and also in your sample preview it is printing in each row.

Comment: `i checked your sample but same printing repeat values for each` - What rows and columns?

Comment: for Slno 3 in your preview, employee has entered intime and outtime so that totalhours should be calculating sum of all intime and outtime of particular employee so it should display 11:00 instead of displaying separetly 5:00 and 6:00 , it is working correctly for my query, Only it should highlight the backcolor only if employee  outtime will be null or blank

Comment: As you can see in my sample the *TotalHours* column contains data from the datasource (the data is not calculated). Do you want that only the row #2 (not the row #3) was highlighted (for group number 2)?

Comment: sory i am able to get your above comment, but i want whichever employee doesn't have outtime entry display backcolor but should not repeat the value please refer **my question output** like that i want

Comment: I don't understand about what repeating values you are talking. I've shown you a way - you can modify the expression for style. The main idea of my post is solving issue with validation style for *textField* (in case using *Grouping* in report). My sample is a working solution - you can make it more complex if you want